# Odoo 10 related field

Tags: field, odoo-10, relational

I created custom field to res.company. But in my other class, i can not call this field,

this field inherited to res.company,

```
company_sicilno = fields.Char(string="Sicil No :")
```

and this field is in my other class,

```
sicil_no = fields.Char(related='res.company.company_sicilno',store=True)
```

i could not find mistake, it does not show any error message. 
How can i call this res.company.company_sicilno in my other field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem

```
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company',string="Company",default=lambda self: self.env['res.company'].search([]))
```

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3):

You should have field company_id:

```
company_id = fields.Many2one(
                    'res.company',
                    string='Company', 
                    default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id )
```

And you can have your related field:

```
sicil_no = fields.Char(related='company_id.company_sicilno',store=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `Many2one` field to achieve this. First you declare a Many2one field for `res.company`

```
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company',string="Company")
```

Now you can have your related field like the following

```
sicil_no = fields.Char(related='company_id.company_sicilno',store=True)
```

`sicil_no` will get value form `company_id` field

Comment: Did you add company_id field in XML views?

Comment: Yes i did 
<span t-field="o.company_id" invisible="1"/>  like that

Comment: and also tried <field name="o.company_id" invisible="1"/> but not working